# Категории и MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Привет всем, появилась трудность. Нужно сделать категории, точнее они уже есть, а как правильно всё вывести, не знаю! Массивы?
Вот есть таблица `category` и есть таблица `topic`, поля её:

```
id author title tags date text  img cat
```

`cat` - там указываются как бы id категории в таблицы `category`,
а `category` содержит

```
id name meta_k  meta_d
```

Вот я даже не знаю, как можно реализовать это? Там что-то вроде такого, если в таблице `topic`  поле `cat` содержит 3, то из таблицы `category` берём 3-ю запись, там название категории.

Answer (score 2):

Читай про `JOIN` в mysql. Запрос в общем случае должен быть вида:

```
SELECT * FROM topic t JOIN category c ON t.cat = category.id
```